# Accessing the base class' methods when instantiating the child class through the interfaces

Tags: c#, inheritance, dependency-injection, interface

I'm trying to understand the Interface implementations with DI and IOC.

I have the interfaces and classes below

```
public interface IApplication
{
    public void Foo();
}

public class Application : IApplication
{
   public void Foo(){//implementation}
}

public interface IHomeService
{
    public void Fly();
}

public class HomeService : Application, IApplication, IHomeService
{
   public void Fly(){ ///implementation}
}
```

Now when I instantiate the HomeService as below:

```
IHomeService service = new HomeService();

service.Fly()//Accesible
service.Foo() // Not Accesible!
```

How can I use the interfaces, so that Foo also becomes accessible in `IHomeService service = new HomeService()`. Should I override the methods again in the HomeService that belongs to `IApplicationService`? Is there any other way around?

The reason I'm using another way is that there are so many child service classes that inherit from this `Application` class.

Comment: If `IHomeService` implies `IApplication` then it should inherit it: `public interface IHomeService : IApplication` otherwise you need to cast `((IApplication)service).Foo();`

Comment: Thank you. So it looks like we will either need to cast to the interface as you showed, or override IApplication methods in the child classes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, with dependency injection you do not manually create objects (with `new`); the container takes care of this for you.

To answer the specific question, `service` is of type `IHomeService` so you can only use members of that interface, irrespective of the runtime type (here `HomeService`).

If you type `service` as `IHomeService`, `HomeService` or implicitly (using `var`), you will be able to call `Foo`.